# Trying to understand database denormalization, Is this database denormalized?

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization, nosql

I've been struggling for a couple of days trying to figure out the best way to design a database of a large data set on Firebase, I even wrote a question on [database administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156039/normalization-vs-denormalization-for-these-kind-of-data) site.

I came up with a design, I don't know that's what's called denormalized data or not. I want to minimize querying time of data and also not making inserting/updating data so hard.

Here's my design:

[image]

Is that the right database design for this kind of data ?
(Please check my [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156039/normalization-vs-denormalization-for-these-kind-of-data) at database administration site for more details about the nature of the data).
But also here's a short description of the data nature:

> So I have an `affiliator_category` which maybe banks, clubs or organisations. And each category contains a number of `affiliators` and each affiliator contains number of `stores` divided into `store_category`, each store has a number of `offers`.
>   And for the user side (the one who do the shopping). A `users` has a number of `memberships` in several `affiliators`, and a number of `spendings` he/she does.

Comment: Like normalization, denormalization is not a yes/no question. It all depends on how your app uses the data. If you want to make your reads simpler, you'll often duplicate more data. If you want to allow for queries on aggregates, you'll end up storing derivable data. Unless you want to consider a very specific use-case, it'll be hard to say something like "this data model is denormalized enough".

Comment: Do you care about the difference between "denormalized" and "unnormalized"?  Some people don't.

Comment: Have you looked into a design called star schema?  This can be really sweet for lots of different kinds of queries, depending on the specific design.  But it can be really difficult to update.  So much so that it is often used in secondary databases like data warehouses or data marts.